# Is standard deviation suitable for error bars in case of time-dependent measures?

Tags: data-visualization, standard-deviation

I'm a software developer so my knowledge of statistics is pretty limited. I will rephrase the question if it sounds confusing.

I'm trying to visualize the data for a networking test in which I performed repeated measures of trasmission time with a varying parameter (package length). For every different value of the parameter I performed 15 measures and then recorded the minimum, maximum, average and standard deviation value for the batch.

I am asked to plot said values in function of the parameter, so I chose a XY scatter chart, but I'm really skeptical of plotting std dev as a separate data series, since it's 2 orders of magnitude smaller than the other three data series.

I think a 'clever' way of showing all the information on the graph would be to add std dev error bars to the mean data points, but since I'm no expert in statistics, I'm not sure whether that would make sense or could be misinterpreted.

From a quick read on Wikipedia, it doesn't seem to be a good idea, since I'm not taking all samples (all possible -infinite- test results at that time) into account, but then again I am not performing measures on a fixed set of data, and my measure is more similar to a stochastic process than to repeated measures of the same quantity (there's an implicit time dependency).

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the error bars? What valid conclusions would you like for someone looking at your bar chart to  be able to draw--presumably without further computation.

Comment: My idea would be to show how far single samples are from average, on average. I am also going to plot minimum and maximum, but they could be outliers, so I want to give an idea of average variation in the same batch. I'm not sure std dev is the most appropriate marker here since I'm not dealing with fully independent measurements.

Comment: The difficulty with trying to put 'error bars' on bars in a bar chard for categorical data is that there is no standard way to do it. The idea is to show how much shorter or taller each bar might have been, but (as you say) that depends on how the data were collected and on the sample size. You must always state the probability model and state the number of counts for each bar, not just percentages.